# Describe the Galois group of a cubic and quartic over $\mathbb{F}_p(y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields, galois-extensions

I'm studying "Note on a problem of Chowla" by Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer, it's about counting the number of values attained by a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

In the paper, for a polinomial $f$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ we study $N(f)$ the number of $y \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that
\begin{equation} f(x) = y \end{equation}
has a root in $\mathbb{F}_p$. Without giving too much detail, $N(f)$ depends only on the degree of $f$, the Galois group of the equation over $\mathbb{F}_p(y)$ and $\mathbb{F}_p^+(y)$ where $^+$ is the algebraic closure.

The thing is I have no idea on how to study Galois groups that are not over $\mathbb{Q}$. In my case, I'm only interested this problem for cubic and quartic but if I can learn a general approach that would be great. More precisely, I would like to be able to describe the group with
\begin{equation} f(x) = x^4 + ax^2 + bx \end{equation}
depending on if $a$ and $b$ are $0$ or not.

For instance, the case that seems the easiest is $a=b=0$, and so I would like to study $x^4-y = 0$ which leads to the field $\mathbb{F}(y)(\zeta_4, \sqrt[4]{y})$ and i'm lost here. I don't even know how things would change whith $\mathbb{F}_p^+(y)$.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Your question is unclear, especially the status of $y$: at the beginning of your post, $y$ seems to belong to $\mathbb{F}_p$, but in the sequel , it seems to be an indeterminate.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, but to be honest it's not quite clear in the article...  Give it a look yourself http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa5/aa545.pdf

Comment: My browser thinks that link is unsafe to open, so I could not check. Anyway, my guess is that they are studying the Galois group over the rational function field.

Comment: Over $\Bbb{F}_p(y)$ the degree of the splitting field of $x^4-y$ depends on $p$. More precisely, whether $\Bbb{F}_p$ contains a fourth root of unity or not. Instead, with $\Bbb{F}_p^+(y)$ this is a non-issue because the algebraic closure contains the said fourth roots of unity automatically.

Comment: But the techniques you need are familiar from elsewhere in field theory. For example, $\Bbb{F}_p[y]$ is a PID (a Euclidean domain even), so Eisenstein's criterion works. Therefore Eisenstein applied to the irreducible polynomial $y$ tells us that $x^4-y$ is irreducible over the field of fractions $\Bbb{F}_p(y)$ etc.